# Tuple type '[Observable<any> | undefined]' of length '1' has no element at index '1' error when destructuring array in function parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to destructure array of 2 length in the callback function in subscribe but I get error `Tuple type '[Observable<any> | undefined]' of length '1' has no element at index '1'`

Without destructuring works the code without problem.

```
export enum Loading {
  Pending = 'Pending',
  Completed = 'Completed',
}

export class TeamFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() mode?: FormMode;
  @Input() team?: Team;
  @Input() playerIds?: string[];
  @Input() loadingCreate$?: Observable<Loading>;
  @Input() error$?: Observable<any>;
  @Output() teamSubmitted = new EventEmitter<Team>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadingCreate$?.pipe(filter((loadingState) => !!loadingState)).subscribe((state) => {
      if (state === Loading.Pending) {
        this.teamForm.disable();
      } else if (state === Loading.Completed) {
        this.teamForm.enable();
      }
    });

    combineLatest([this.loadingCreate$,this.error$ ])
      .pipe()
      .subscribe(([loading,error]) => console.log(loading,error));
  }
```

Below is the selector for `error$`

```
export const selectErrorByTempId = (props: { tempId: string }) =>
  createSelector(selectTeamsState, (state) => {
    return state.loadingTeamByTempId[props.tempId]?.error;
  });
```

Comment: I’d expect this to work. However, I’m not seeing error$ set anywhere?

Comment: `combineLatest([this.loadingCreate$,this.error$ ])
      .pipe()
      .subscribe(([loading,...error]) => console.log(loading,error));` This works but It does not make sense to wrap error in array

Comment: works fine [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxY0GW)

Comment: I’m surprised it doesn’t break on the combineLatest? Are you setting error$ somewhere? Doesn’t look assigned in what you posted?

Comment: @MikeOne error$ comes from parent as `Observable<any>`. Possible values for error is `null` and `string`.

Comment: Ah sure.. Input - duh . Still possible that is part of the problem though.. does it help if you either use error$! Instead of ? Or actually assign it (maybe with a Subject)?

Comment: @MikeOne ! does not help. But combineLatest seems to be deprecated even thought I have imported it from `rxjs` not `rxjs/operators`. and the version is 7

Comment: That’s a known issue with combineLatest I think. Don’t worry it’s not (https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest)

Comment: @MikeOne this works fine `combineLatest([of('hede'), of('hodo')]).subscribe(([data1, data2]) => console.log(data1, data2));` I think I have problem with source observables, `error$` or `loadingCreate$` Because they come through `@Input()` ?

Comment: Indeed. I think one of those might be undefined and combineLatest therefore only emits an array with a single value (hence the error)

Comment: The output of the following expression is as follow `combineLatest([this.loadingCreate$, this.error$]).subscribe((loadingError) => console.log(loadingError));` `['Pending', undefined]` , `['Pending', null]` , `['Completed', 'Http failure response for http://localhost:4291/api/v1/teamss: 404 Not Found']`

Comment: I have found the problem. The parameters of the array in `combineLatest` cannot be undefined but only `Observable`. With type guard I have guaranteed this requirements. @MikeOne